# Subtract rows based on many columns

Tags: r

I have this data.frame

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("site1", 3), rep("site2", 8), rep("site3", 9), rep("site4", 15)),
                 major_rock = c("greywacke",    "mudstone", "gravel",   "greywacke",    "gravel",   "mudstone", "gravel", "mudstone", "mudstone",   
                                "conglomerate", "gravel", "mudstone",   "greywacke","conglomerate", "gravel",   "gravel",   "greywacke","gravel",   
                                "greywacke",    "gravel",   "mudstone", "greywacke",    "gravel", "gravel", "gravel",   "conglomerate", "greywacke",
                                "coquina",  "gravel",   "gravel",   "greywacke",    "gravel",   "mudstone","mudstone",  "gravel"),
                 minor_rock = c("sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",  "limestone",   "sand silt clay", "sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",
                                "sand silt clay", "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", NA, "limestone",  "mudstone sandstone coquina limestone",
                                "sandstone mudstone limestone",  "sand loess silt",  "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", "sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",
                                "sandstone mudstone limestone", "sand loess silt", "loess silt sand", "sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt",
                                "sand silt clay",  "sandstone mudstone conglomerate", "loess sand silt", "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", "sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",
                                "sand loess silt", "sand silt clay", "loess silt sand",  "sandstone mudstone limestone", "sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt",
                                "limestone", "loess sand silt",  NA, "sandstone mudstone conglomerate", "sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite", "limestone",
                                "mudstone sandstone coquina limestone", "mudstone tephra loess"),
                 area_ha = c(1066.68,   7.59,   3.41,   4434.76,    393.16, 361.69, 306.75, 124.93, 95.84,  9.3,    8.45,   4565.89,    2600.44,    2198.52,    
                             2131.71,   2050.09,    1640.47,    657.09, 296.73, 178.12, 10403.53,   8389.2,  8304.08,   3853.36,    2476.36,    2451.25,    
                             1640.47,   1023.02,    532.94, 385.68, 296.73, 132.45, 124.93, 109.12, 4.87))
```

In it, there are 4 sites, 2 of them are ***independent*** (`site1` and `site3` ; they don't include any site upstream) and 2 are ***dependent*** (`site2` and `site4`; they include upstream site(s))

I want to create a new data.frame, let's call it `df_indep`. In which, I want all sites to be ***independent*** which means subtracting any upstream site(s) from the dependent sites as below

> site1 and site3 will remain the same as they are independent
>
> site2 (independent) = site2 - site1
>
> site4 (independent) = site4 -(site2+site3)

Below is `df` only for `major_rock` and `minor_rock` combinations that have `area_percent` larger than 15% (before subtracting upstream sites; `site2` and `site3`)

```
library(dplyr)
head(df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
       mutate(area_percent = area_ha/sum(area_ha)*100) %>% 
       filter(area_percent>5),15)


#       id   major_rock                                             minor_rock  area_ha area_percent
#   <fctr>       <fctr>                                                 <fctr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#1   site1    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone  1066.68    98.979289
#2   site2    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone  4434.76    77.329604
#3   site2       gravel                                         sand silt clay   393.16     6.855592
#4   site2     mudstone                  sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra   361.69     6.306845
#5   site2       gravel                                                     NA   306.75     5.348848
#6   site3     mudstone                  sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra  4565.89    27.978879
#7   site3    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone  2600.44    15.934986
#8   site3 conglomerate                           sandstone mudstone limestone  2198.52    13.472099
#9   site3       gravel                                        sand loess silt  2131.71    13.062701
#10  site3       gravel                                        loess silt sand  2050.09    12.562550
#11  site3    greywacke sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt  1640.47    10.052479
#12  site4     mudstone                  sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra 10403.53    25.925869
#13  site4    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone  8389.20    20.906106
#14  site4       gravel                                        sand loess silt  8304.08    20.693984
#15  site4       gravel                                         sand silt clay  3853.36     9.602674
```

and here is the

**FINAL RESULT**

I want after subtracting upstream sites

```
#       id   major_rock                                             minor_rock area_ha area_percent
#1   site1    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone 1066.68    98.979289
#2   site2    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone 3368.08    72.319849
#3   site2       gravel                                         sand silt clay  389.75     8.368762
#4   site2     mudstone                  sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra  361.69     7.766254
#5   site2       gravel                                                     NA  306.75     6.586576
#6   site3     mudstone                  sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra 4565.89    27.978879
#7   site3    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone 2600.44    15.934986
#8   site3 conglomerate                           sandstone mudstone limestone 2198.52    13.472099
#9   site3       gravel                                        sand loess silt 2131.71    13.062701
#10  site3       gravel                                        loess silt sand 2050.09    12.562550
#11  site3    greywacke sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt 1640.47    10.052479
#12  site4     mudstone                  sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra 5475.95    30.297305
#13  site4    greywacke              sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone 1354.00     7.491403
#14  site4       gravel                                        sand loess silt 6163.92    34.103701
#15  site4       gravel                                         sand silt clay 2803.11    15.509031
```

I will appreciate any suggestions on how to do this in R.

**UPDATE**

This is a map showing all 4 sites

[image]

The figure below shows `site4` (accumulative as in `df`) and `site1` (independent) as I want in the final output after subtracting `site2` and `site3`

[image]

The figure below shows the same for site2 (accumulative) and indepenendent
[image]

Regarding @rbierman's question of how sites dependcies are encoded, please check below.

```
#      id dependent dep_site1 dep_site2 dep_site3
#1  site1        no        no        no        no
#2  site1        no        no        no        no
#3  site1        no        no        no        no
#4  site2       yes       yes        no        no
#5  site2       yes       yes        no        no
#6  site2       yes       yes        no        no
#7  site2       yes       yes        no        no
#8  site2       yes       yes        no        no
#9  site2       yes       yes        no        no
#10 site2       yes       yes        no        no
#11 site2       yes       yes        no        no
#12 site3        no        no        no        no
#13 site3        no        no        no        no
#14 site3        no        no        no        no
#15 site3        no        no        no        no
#16 site3        no        no        no        no
#17 site3        no        no        no        no
#18 site3        no        no        no        no
#19 site3        no        no        no        no
#20 site3        no        no        no        no
#21 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#22 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#23 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#24 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#25 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#26 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#27 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#28 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#29 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#30 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#31 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#32 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#33 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#34 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
#35 site4       yes       yes       yes       yes
```

Comment: If you already have the final result that you want, what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Samuel
I got the final result for 4 sites ONLY using Microsoft Excel. My data include around 150 sites. I just presented 4 sites in this reproducible example to help anyone who will answer the question get an idea about the output I want. So, my question is "how can I get the final result (that I got through Excel) using R?"

Comment: You mention subtracting, what exactly entails this operation regarding your data? Could you explain a little. I am still confused as to what you need help with.

Comment: @Samuel
Please, check the update. The whole idea is any rock that exist in site1 or site2 or site3 will definitely exist in site4 as it includes all other sites. So I want to find the rocks that exist only in site4 after subtracting other sites.

Comment: how are the site dependencies encoded? If you gave me all 150 sites how would I know if site 76 is independent or not?

Comment: @rbierman
Please, check update

Comment: @rbierman
If site76 is `independent` it will have **no**  in column `dependent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too bad, just a little renaming and joining.

First we'll want dependencies in a nice two-column format. You can use `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather` on the wide dependencies you posted to make them long:

```
deps = data.frame(
    id = c("site2", "site4", "site4"),
    dependency = c("site1", "site2", "site3"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
#      id dependency
# 1 site2      site1
# 2 site4      site2
# 3 site4      site3
```

Using `dplyr` for joins, we'll also want `character` rather than `factor` columns just in case the levels aren't all the same.

```
    library(dplyr)    
df = mutate_at(df, .cols = c("id", "major_rock", "minor_rock"), .funs = funs(as.character))
```

First we create a "dependency with measure" data frame that has a clearly *dependent* name for the area and id (**edit**) and then we aggregate it to the `id` level, summing the dependent areas:

```
dep_w_measure = df %>%
    select(dependency = id, major_rock, minor_rock, dep_area = area_ha) %>%
    inner_join(deps) %>%
    group_by(id, major_rock, minor_rock) %>%
    summarize(dep_area = sum(dep_area))
```

Then we join that to the original data, and subtract off the dependent area (where present):

```
result = left_join(df, dep_w_measure, by = c("major_rock", "minor_rock", "id")) %>%
    mutate(area_ind = area_ha - coalesce(dep_area, 0))
head(result)
#      id major_rock                                minor_rock area_ha dep_area area_ind
# 1 site1  greywacke sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone 1066.68       NA  1066.68
# 2 site1   mudstone                                 limestone    7.59       NA     7.59
# 3 site1     gravel                            sand silt clay    3.41       NA     3.41
# 4 site2  greywacke sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone 4434.76  1066.68  3368.08
# 5 site2     gravel                            sand silt clay  393.16     3.41   389.75
# 6 site2   mudstone     sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra  361.69       NA   361.69
```

I left the `dep_area` and `area_ha` columns in to "show my work", you can clean it up as needed. The independent area `area_ind` column matches the `area_ha` in your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your time, help and this nice approach. It worked fine for site2 but I don't think it works for site4. For example, site4 in my desired output (with major_rock "mudstone" and minor_rock "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra" equals 5475.95 ha because it is site4-(site2+site3) but in your answer it is (site4-site2) and (site4-site3) = 10041.84+ 5837.64 = 15879.48 ha which is even higher than the original accumulative value for site4 in df that equals 10403.53 ha

Comment: Hmmm, I think the approach can be adapted. We need to add a step before the subtraction where we group by `id`, `major_rock`, and `minor_rock`, and sum the dependent areas. Then, this *sum* of dependent areas should be subtracted from `area_ha`. I think that should work. I won't have time to write it up for a few hours.

Comment: Thanks! Now you awarded the bounty I had to find time to clean it up - added the aggregation in.

Comment: Many thanks Gregor. Even without cleaning, you answer was great. The bounty is nothing compared to your great answer and the time you spent trying to help me. I really appreciate your time and help.